# PowerMockRunner isn't recognized but all dependencies are in place

Tags: java, maven, mockito, powermock

In my unit test, PowerMockRunner isn't recognized, although i have all dependencies I need in my pom, and all required jars downloaded. I'm trying to test a static method.  I keep getting the error `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<PowerMockRunner> to Class<? extends Runner>"` `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` . Why is PowerMockRunner now recognized? I'm pretty sure all my dependencies have been added. I'm using junit4. This is my pom file:

NOTE: this is not a duplicate post.  My question acknowledges that certain dependencies are needed in order to run PowerMock, but this particular question asks why, after having added all those dependencies, PowerMockRunner.class is still not recognized.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.vismark</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestingTraining</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TestingTraining</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my simple test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(UserDAO.class)
public class UserDAOTest {

    @Test
    public void createShouldReturnUserId() {
        UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(UserDAO.class);

        when(IDGenerator.generateId()).thenReturn(1);

        int result = dao.create(new User());

        assertEquals(1, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add powermock-module-junit4-common

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Good catch.  This is an old question, but this answer worked for me.  I probably would have lost a good bit of time solving this without your help, since the error wouldn't really imply that this library has anything to do with the problem.